# Cannot read property send of undefined in module discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

When trying to send a message to a specific person, I get the error `Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`.

Here is the module code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'bugreport',
    description: 'Report a bug to the developer.',
    args: true,
    usage: `<message>`,
    cooldown: 60,
    aliases: [],
    execute(message, args, prefix, ownerid) {
        for (i = 0; i < ownerid.length; i++) {
            const dmme = message.client.users.cache.get(ownerid[i]);
            const bugreportembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('New bug report!')
            .addField('Info', `From ${message.author.tag}`)
            .addField('Description', message.content.replace(`${prefix}bugreport `, ""))
            dmme.send(bugreportembed)
            message.channel.send('Sent!')
        } 
    },
};
```

I tried using await when getting the users from the cache, but apparently I can't use await in modules. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Because something went wrong and the `channel` object doesn't exist inside the `message`.

Comment: When removing that line completely, I don't get an error anymore, but the message wont send to the dmme variable, when I put it back, it doesen't throw an error anymore, but still wont send the message.

Comment: What exactly is `ownerid`? How do you execute it?

Comment: @MrMythical ownerid is an array of ids belonging to the bot owner(s)

Comment: Can you please send exactly what it looks like?

Comment: Maybe it could be you put `i = 0` instead of something like `let i = 0`

Comment: Your message isn't an message object, meaning its something else other than a message. So check your parameter while getting and check if that parameter and the parameters of `run()` function is in the same order, as well as same number or not.

Comment: Ok yes please send which line is throwing the error. We can’t tell if it’s `dmme.send()` or `message.channel.send()`

Comment: @MrMythical the array looks like this: `"ownerid":["12345678901234567890", "12345678901234567890"]`

Comment: @MrMythical its throwing the error on dmme.send(bugreportembed), but the error is only thrown when the for loop is in place, so I think the for loop thinks there is nothing in the array, and skips over it, so I must be defining ownerid wrong at some point

Comment: Can I see exactly how you execute this command in your main file (default name for the file is index.js). Also, doing `for (i = 0;` is wrong. You need to make it a declared variable. `for (let i = 0;`

Comment: @MrMythical It is executed with: `try {
  command.execute(message, args, prefix, client, ownerid);
 } catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  message.reply('There was an error trying to execute that command!');
 }`

Comment: I will try with let i = 0; Edit: still no response, probably somehow didnt define ownerid correctly

Comment: Well, in the part where you execute it, it shows you put client. Remove that and it should work. Or add a `client ` parameter to your execute function. (In your command file you only put message args prefix ownerid)

Comment: @MrMythical I removed client from the execution line, still no response, I've tried everything, ready to just rewrite the command at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
const dmme = client.users.cache.get(ownerid[i]);
```

Instead of

```
 const dmme = message.client.users.cache.get(ownerid[i]);
```

Comment: No, message.client must be used.

Comment: MrMythical is correct, as this is in a module, I have to pass the client through the message, thus message.client.